# How to Send this API Call to Twilio Flow via CFHTTP

Tags: coldfusion, twilio-api

So I'm trying to setup the API call to Twilio Flow using CFHTTP but am having no luck. Keeps returning CFHTTP doesn't exist when I try to view the response.

I've already tried adjusting from formfields to body, setting the charset to utf-8, etc. I was successfully able to send an SMS using the Programmable SMS portion but am having no luck hitting the Flow.

```
<cfset twilioUsername = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<cfset twilioFlowSid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<cfset twilioPassword = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />

<cfset twilioFrom = "+1XXXXXXXXXX" />
<cfset twilioTo = "+1XXXXXXXXXX" />

<cfset bodyFields = {
    "name" : "Tester",
    "cases" : "This Case this Time"
} />

<cfset twilioFlowResource = (
    "https://studio.twilio.com/v1/Flows/#twilioFlowSid#/Executions.json"
    ) />

<cfhttp result="POST" method="POST" charset="utf-8" url="#twilioFlowResource#" username="#twilioUsername#" password="#twilioPassword#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="From" value="twilioFrom" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="To" value="twilioTo" />
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="Parameters" value="#serializeJSON(bodyFields)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

All I keep receiving is variable CFHTTP doesn't exist when I try to view the contents of cfhttp.filecontent.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion

Comment: It is because you used the `result` attribute which *".. Lets you specify an alternate variable in which to receive a result"*. Meaning CF won't populate the default variable name `cfhttp`. In [your example](https://trycf.com/gist/d0e7e6e2aebd989ec180eb93409d1130/acf2016?theme=monokai), you should dump the variable name "POST".  Though for clarity, I'd recommend using a different variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you used [cfhttp's "result" attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html) which *".. lets you specify an alternate variable in which to receive a result"*. Meaning CF won't populate the default variable named `cfhttp`. So in your example, you should be dumping the variable named `#POST#`. (Though to avoid further confusion, I'd recommend using something else, like "response".)

```
<cfhttp result="response" 
    method="POST" 
    charset="utf-8" 
    url="#twilioFlowResource#" 
    username="#twilioUsername#" 
    password="#twilioPassword#">

    ... parameters ...
</cfhttp>

<cfdump var="#response#">
```

---

Also, perhaps it's just a typo, but ... if that's the actual code you're using, it's missing pound signs around the variables in the `<cfhttpparam>` declarations. So the code is actually sending the literal string "twilioFrom" instead of the variable value: `+1XXXXXXXXXX`. These lines:

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="From" value="twilioFrom" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="To" value="twilioTo" />
```

... should be changed to this:

```
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="From" value="#twilioFrom#" />
<cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="To" value="#twilioTo#" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much, yes the value missing pound signs were just typos adjusting things for posting on here, but the result was the issue. I had this in there as it worked for posting to their SMS gateway but broke this part for the Flow gateway

Comment: You're welcome :-) BTW, the reason I suggest changing the variable name is that even I missed the "result" variable on first read.  I saw "POST" and my brain kicked into autocompletion gear and translated it into *method* = 
"POST" ;-)